# Can we write $\sum_{k=n}^\infty\sum_{\ell=0}^k a_\ell b_{k-\ell}$ as a product of series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-product

We have the Cauchy product
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty b_\ell=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{\ell=0}^k a_\ell b_{k-\ell}.
$$
Do we have a way of writing
$$
\tag{1}
\sum_{k=n}^\infty\sum_{\ell=0}^k a_\ell b_{k-\ell}=\sum_{k=?}^\infty a_?\sum_{\ell=?}^\infty b_?,
$$
where $n=1,2,\dots$?

Certainly,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=n}^\infty\sum_{\ell=0}^k a_\ell b_{k-\ell}
&=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\left(\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1}+\sum_{\ell=n}^k\right) a_\ell b_{k-\ell}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{\ell=0}^k a_{\ell+n} b_{k-\ell}+\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1}a_\ell\sum_{k=0}^\infty  b_{k+n-\ell}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{k+n}\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty b_\ell+\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1}a_\ell\sum_{k=0}^\infty  b_{k+n-\ell}.
\end{aligned}
$$
However, I am curious if the "Cauchy product" in (1) can be written as a single product of two series without the additional sum $\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1}$.

**Edit:**
One thought I did have was to use differentiation and write something of the form
$$
\partial_x^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{\ell=0}^k a_\ell b_{k-\ell}x^k|_{x=1}.
$$
Then you can factor out the product and differentiate. This of course doesn't exactly work but could be a potential lead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seek to factorize $\sum_{\ell+m\ge n}a_\ell b_m$. Since this includes an $a_0b_n$ term, your sum over $a$s needs to start at $a_0$. By the same logic, the sum over $b$s needs to start at $b_0$. So it's only possible if $n=0$.